# Locking searchbar at top of tableView

Tags: ios, swift

My tableview layout is such that I have a fixed searchbar at the top of a tableview. So the searchbar stays at the top and does not scroll with UITableView.  Although I have the layout that i desire, my tableView shows no cell details (showing blank).  Please can someone advise on where I am going wrong?

my Layout:

[image]

[image]

TestTableViewController

```
 class TestTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate{

var itemstore: ItemStore!



// Sets how many rows in the table view to display
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return itemstore.allItems.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    let name = itemstore.allItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = name

    return cell
}
}
```

ItemStore

```
 class ItemStore {

var allItems = ["Thanh", "David", "Tommy", "Maria"]

 }
```

AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Create ItemStore instance
    let itemStoreObject = ItemStore()
    let itemController = window!.rootViewController as! TestTableViewController
    itemController.itemstore = itemStoreObject

    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you wired up the table view datasource and delegate in Interface Builder?

Comment: please could you expand on your question. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Did you IBOutlet your tableview?
Also check did you connect tableview datasource and delegate?

Comment: @iuser, please could you tell me how to connect the tableview datasource and delegate?

Comment: Plz check the link --- https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/1464517948Add_Delegates.gif


If you still face any issue let me know.

Comment: @iUser After IBOutlet by tableView, how do i reference it in the two required UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: @tim IBOutlet tableview and connect delegate and datasource as shown in GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point in cellForRowAt function and see if you can get there. Check data source and delegate wiring if the break point is not reached. You are probably looking for something like this in your viewDidLoad function:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

If the break point is reached and you still cannot see anything, check the height for each cell.